# Как избежать использование глобальной переменной в DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

Слышал что использовать глобальные переменные очень плохо. Можно ли как-то совсем избавиться в этом случае?
Например есть плагин загрузки какого либо изображения и перевода его в обычный формат.

```
CPlugIn* plugin;

extern "C"{
__declspec(dllexport) bool PlugInStart( void ){
    plugin = new CPlugIn(/*params*/)
    if( !plugin ){
         /*error*/
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}

__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* PlugInGetImage( const std::string& file_name ){
   return plugin->LoadFile( const std::string& file_name );
}

__declspec(dllexport) void PlugInStop( void ){
    delete plugin;
}
}
```

Comment: Из вашего примера кода совершенно не ясно, должен ли клиентский код обращаться непосредственно к  указателю, или он должен иметь дело с функциями. Если он должен иметь дело только с функциями, то зачем вы объявили указатель глобальным?

Comment: Вообще говоря, если бы глобальные переменные были только злом, их бы из языков убирали, но они, очевидно, как и goto, в некоторых местах необходимы. Судя по типу и имени вашей переменной ее глобальное назначение можно оправдать - с ней работает низкоуровневый DLL-модуль целиком. Плохие глобальные переменные - это переменные в духе "int i", "bool tmp_1, tmp_2" и т.д. Так что если ваше беспокойство вызвано лишь семантическим аспектом - можете не беспокоиться.

Comment: `new` кстати, кидает исключение при невозможности выделить память. Для проверки на `nullptr` нужно добавлять [`nothrow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае у вас получился [одиночка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), судя по приведенным фрагментам. Хотя при широком распространении одиночки и проявляются те же проблемы что и у глобальных переменных. В вашем случае это скорее деталь реализации. Поэтому ничего делать не нужно, в таком виде терпимо.

Однако, хотел бы заметить, что ваши функции `PlugInStart` и `PlugInStop` выглядят скорее излишними. Их нужно вызывать в [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) так как клиенту совсем необязательно знать, что расширению нужны какие-то дополнительные пинки для работы. Другими словами, таким дизайном вы своими руками декапсулируете детали реализации.

Comment: Ну, в `DllMain` обычно нельзя делать ничего нетривиального, прямо или косвенно. Вот список того, что нельзя: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx (например, запускать thread'ы и ожидать события).

Answer (score 1):

> Слышал что использовать глобальные переменные очень плохо

Слышать мало, надо понимать.

Не следует вестись на «распространенные» мнения, даже если вам нашептывает по телефону сам Александреску. **Решает здравый смысл**.

Сколько уж копий сломано в спорах по поводу глобальных переменных, по поводу использования оператора `goto`. А воз и ныне там. Не «популярность» конструкций решает качество кода, а их уместность текущему применению.

### На примерах

Нам нужен объект `Config`. Сделав его синглтоном, или просто структурой глобального доступа мы не теряем ничего. Оверхед нулевой! Он один. Сделав «сеттеры» и «геттеры» потокобезопасными, мы вообще будем кросавчеги. Но мы можем его гонять ссылками по объектам ... только для того, чтобы посоны сказали: «Ба, да у тебя нет глобальных объектов, ты кодишь как приняло большинство!»

**Да да, конечно: десятки тысяч мух не могут ошибаться — это мед!**

Нужен ли нужен оператор `goto`? Да или нет? «Правильные посоны» авторитетно заявят — не нужен. Есть же примитивные функциональные конструкции, которыми можно построить всё. Только «левые» прогеры это пользуют.

Позволю вам напомнить — задачи бывают разные. К примеру, построить автомат на разряженной матрице состояний (ну, к примеру 500x500) гораздо проще на элементарных `switch`(по сути `goto`), чем строить -дцать вложенных друг в друга `if`/`while`/`do`.

### Ну а теперь предметно

> загрузки какого либо изображения

Сущность «изображение» для приложения понятие отнюдь не глобальное. Если честно, кроме «конфига» (возможно, состояний), я больше не вижу претендентов на глобальную область видимости.